# how to auto dismiss UIAlertView when app becomes active

Tags: xcode, ios7

OK, I have an app that runs a timer. If the user is watching the app's timer count down (e.g. the app is awake and active in the foreground) I want an alert to be shown to the user. I've added this code to my timer when it reaches 0:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder" message:@"It's time!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
```

The problem I'm having is that if I put the phone to sleep or make the app inactive in some other fashion I have a local notification setup to handle this alerting so when the user goes back to the app I don't want them to see the alert mentioned above. It's an unnecessary "click" they have to make.

Is there a way to auto dismiss this alert when the app either goes into the background or enters the foreground if it's been triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use NSNotificationcenter at the UIAlertview definition.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

[alert show];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] usingBlock:^(NSNotification* notification){
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no auto dismiss.

You have to communicate that your app become active (from `UIApplicationDelegate`) to your `UIAlertView`.

To do so, many techniques exists, you could keep reference of that alert in `AppDelegate` to dismiss it, or use some `NSNotification` posted from delegate and observed in your `ViewController` or anywhere you are showing this alert.

Comment: Thanks Vincent, but I'm not sure how to 'keep reference' of the alert in the appDelegate? Any sample code would be appreciated...

Comment: Thanks Vincent... very helpful. I'm just trying to finish what I started so I can actually move on from Objective-C to Swift as to not waste any more 'learning' time on the former.

Comment: Learning Objective-C is not a waste of time since it won't disappear as soon as you would "hope". Plus many concepts (like ARC) comes from it, so you would benefit from learning it. Like you would benefit from learning C... And sorry to bother you, but Swift is not easier than Objective-C. If you do not know what "keeping a reference of an object" is, it is not a matter of language, but basic programming knowledge, which I can't help you there. I did not want to be rude when I told you to go read some books. That's is the truth, you should learn Programming, not a "language".

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use... https://github.com/sdarlington/WSLViewAutoDismiss